# How to raise if an action method is missing in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, actioncontroller

I learnt from [rails 3 rendering view without action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20138550/rails-3-rendering-view-without-action) that it's possible for a request to handle a request even if there's no public controller method corresponding to the action.

Is it possible in Rails 3 to configure the development environment to automatically raise in such a scenario by modifying `config/environments/development.rb` to fail if there isn't a public (as opposed to protected or private) controller method corresponding to the action?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this in your `ApplictionController`

```
  before_filter :check_action, if: 'Rails.env.development?'

  private

  def check_action
    unless respond_to?(params[:action])
      raise NoMethodError, "#{params[:controller]} controller has no #{params[:action]} action"
    end
  end
```